# Facing Issue while importing ZBar in XCode 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my Case Importing ZBAR in xcode 7.3 work fine but samething I want to do in XCode 8.1 it showing **linker command fail error**.

How to resolve it?

Is there is Any Difference between Xcode 7.3 & Xcode 8.1.

Comment: What is ZBAR ? Other thing you have to update libraries(i.e are used in your project) in order to use Xcode8.1.

Comment: ZBarSDK(libzbar.a)

Comment: You should get a much more detailed error message. You might have an issue with missing architectures.

Comment: which additional labraries i have to add for ZBarSDK(libzbar.a) in xcode 8.1 as compair to xcode 7.3.

Comment: Do you have pods for this ZBAR ?